# Summing array elements in Hive

Tags: arrays, hive, sum

I have the following table:

```
user_id, items_x, items_y
1, [0, 1, 3, 0], [1, 0, 0, 1]
2, [1, 1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 2]
3, [2, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 4, 0]
```

I want to get following results, summing the elements in the arrays:

```
user_id, items_x, items_y
1, 4, 2
2, 3, 3
3, 3, 4
```

It should be possible to use "explode" and aggregate for each column separately but that solution is quite complicated when I have 6 columns to do it for.

Is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: is the length of array fixed/known beforehand?

Comment: Yes, it is fixed an known beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the *array length is known beforehand*, the simplest way is to get the elements by index and add.

```
select user_id,items_x[0]+items_x[1]+items_x[2]+items_x[3],items_y[0]+items_y[1]+items_y[2]+items_y[3]
from tbl
```

Comment: @howach, Please consider **accepting and upvoting** the answer..!!